# What is the story and purpose of Lord Vishnu's Vaikuntha avatara?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, avatars

The 24 avataras of Lord Vishnu are described in Skandha one  chapter three of  [**Shreemad Bhagvat Purana**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3) . 
It also mentioned that   the incarnations of the Lord are innumerable.
Apart from these 24 , there are lots of other incarnation of Lord Vishnu  mentioned in Shreemad Bhagvatam.

For example , a avatara of Lord Vishnu called  [**"Vaikuntha"**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/5/4)  is mentioned in Skanda 8 chapter 5

> पत्नी विकुण्ठा शुभ्रस्य वैकुण्ठैः सुरसत्तमैः ।
>  तयोः स्वकलया जज्ञे
>   वैकुण्ठो भगवान्स्वयम् ॥8.5.4॥
>
> From the combination of Subhra and his wife, Vikunṭha, there appeared
>   the Supreme Personality of Godhead, Vaikunṭha, along with demigods who
>   were His personal plenary expansions.

It's also said  in the next verse that Lord Vishnu , inorder to please Shree Laxmi created the vaikuntha abode , upon request of her.

I am interested to know more about this Vaikuntha Avatara.

---

So my question is -:

**1.What is the story  and purpose of Lord Vishnu's Vaikuntha Avatara?**

Did Lord Vishnu took this avatara just to create Vaikuntha abode or also to accomplish some other task?

Comment: In Mahabharta [Shanti Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c042.htm), Krishna (Vishnu) says He is called Vaikunta because "He united Earth with Water, Space with Mind, and Wind with Light" at beginning of creation. His powers have no hindrance (Kunthitha)

Comment: Yes , here I think Vishnu took incarnation from his parents ,who is having similar names. And then the Vaikuntha abode on request of Laxmi. So there seems to be some kind of story associated with this avatara. The verses just doesn't seems to be symbolic.

Comment: We're not likely to find much information about Vishnu's incarnation Vaikuntha in Hindu scripture, because he lived in the Raivata Manvantara.  In the Puranas Vyasa spends most of his time either talking about events that happened recently or events that happened in the beginning of the Kalpa or Mahakalpa.  He doesn't spend that much time talking about events that happened between the Swayambhuva Manvantara and the Vaivasvata Manvantara, although the churning of the ocean and Gajendra Moksha are two exceptions.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - Yes ,you are correct , this avatara is from Raivata Manvantara. Lets hope we will get some information if someone is successful in  finding more about this . :-)

Comment: @SwiftPushkar, KeshavSrinivasan : Which source says that Vaikuntha  incarnation is from Raivata Manvantara and not from Chakshus Manvantara?

Comment: @YDS- श्रीशुक उवाच
राजन्नुदितमेतत् ते हरेः कर्माघनाशनम् ।
गजेन्द्रमोक्षणं पुण्यं रैवतं त्वन्तरं शृणु ॥1॥ ---https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/5/1

Answer (score 3):

**What is the story of Lord Vishnu's Vaikuntha Avatara?**

In 6th or Chakshus Manvantara, Lord Vishńu was born as Vaikuntha from Vikunthi/Vikunthaa.

[image: Vishnu Purana - Part 3- Chapter 1]

Here is the English Translation ([Vishnu Purana - Part 3 - Chapter 1](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp075.htm))

> The excellent Hari was again born in the Raivata Manwantara (5th), of Sambhúti, as Mánasa, along with the gods called Abhútarajasas.
>
> **In the next period (6th), Vishńu was born of Vikunthi, as Vaikuntha, along with the deities called Vaikunthas**.
>
> In the present Manwantara (7th), Vishńu was again born as Vámana, the son of Kaśyapa by Adití.

**What is the purpose of Lord Vishnu's Vaikuntha Avatara?**

As per [Mahabharata - Book 12 - Section 342](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c042.htm),

> I have united the Earth with Water, Space with Mind, and Wind with Light. Therefore ant I called Vaikuntha.

Comment: That Shanti Parva verse is explaining the meaning of Vishnu's name Vaikuntha.  It is not talking about Vishnu's incarnation as Vikuntha's son Vaikuntha.   The same chapter also says he has the name Krishna because he tills the Earth in the form of a large black ploughshare.  But that doesn't mean that that large black ploughshare is the Devaki 's son Krishna :-) Vishnu's incarnations are often referred to by Vishnu's names (and vice versa.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan And how Vishnu's name Vaikuntha is different from Vishnu's incarnation as Vikuntha's son Vaikuntha? Don't u think in this chapter of Mahabharata, Krishna talks about his previous incarnation...

Comment: Not necessarily previous incarnations of Vishnu, in many cases it's just talking about names of Vishnu.  Like I said, Vishnu's incarnations are often named after names of Vishnu.

Comment: Then I believe in opposite theory...As per my belief Vishnu's name are formed after his incarnations only...

Comment: Well, Vishnu's names are eternal.  For instance, Vishnu was known as Vasudeva long before the time of Krishna.  And many names of Vishnu are given in the Vedas, which are eternal.

Comment: I m not talking about few eternal names here..Vaikuntha is not eternal name it came after Lord's incarnation..